How can I handle redirection from a home page to a private route within a routing file if they are 'logged in'
I have routing file like this:
{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('./features/login/login.component').then((m) => m.LoginComponent),
      },
      {
        path: 'horse-catalogue',
        canMatch: [isLoggedIn],
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('./features/horse-catalogue/horse-catalogue.component').then(
            (m) => m.HorseCatalogueComponent
          ),
        resolve: { data: horseCatalogueResolver },
      },
   ...
}

export const isLoggedIn: CanMatchFn = () => {
  const authService = inject(AuthenticationService);
  return authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(map((user) => !!user));
};

authService.isLoggedIn() will make a network call to determine if the user is logged in (which I'm doing because a logged in user is issued a HttpOnly, Secure cookie; so I can't read the cookie on the frontend. I wanted to follow a pattern where all the validation is done on the server).
I initially thought of creating another guard to attach to the HomeComponent which will do something similar (it'll just check the inverse of isLoggedIn), but I felt that calling a verify endpoint for every user that's not logged in seemed a bit overkill. I've also got an interceptor, which captures a 401 on all endpoints, and displays a notification to the user saying 'Unauthorised', which I wouldn't want the user to see as soon as they navigate to the application.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle this declaratively with guards?

Try to use canActivate instead canMatch.
